# How to implement blob storage access timeout and show message

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to show message to end user when blob is taking so much time for uploading and downloading. I found useful blog [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2011/02/03/overview-of-retry-policies-in-the-windows-azure-storage-client-library.aspx).

**Simply linear retry policy**

```
 public static RetryPolicy LinearRetry(int retryCount, TimeSpan intervalBetweenRetries)
{
  return () =>
  {
       return (int currentRetryCount, Exception lastException, out TimeSpan retryInterval) =>
       { 
           // Do custom work here               
           // Set backoff
           retryInterval = intervalBetweenRetries;    
           // Decide if we should retry, return bool
           return currentRetryCount < retryCount;          

       };
  };
```

}

But here I didn't get how to send response to user back while retrying. Is this right way or anything else. Please suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`OperationContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.operationcontext_members.aspx) class in Storage Client Library has an event called [`Retrying`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.operationcontext.retrying.aspx) that you can consume and send message back to the client.

For example, I created a simple console application which tries to create a blob container. When I ran this application, I deliberately turned off Internet access so that I can simulate a situation where operation would be retried. Then in this event consumer, I simply write something back to console. You could simply raise another event from there that would send a message back to your client.

```
        var requestOptions = new BlobRequestOptions()
        {
            RetryPolicy = new ExponentialRetry(),
        };
        var operationContext = new OperationContext();
        operationContext.Retrying += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm retrying ....");
        };
        var cloudStorageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
        var blobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("test");
        container.CreateIfNotExists(requestOptions, operationContext);
```

Comment: Thanks thats what exactly I want.